# addressDictionary is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use @properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

I'm working with to get locations and address. For i'm getting location successfully but at the time getting address i'm getting warning like,

> 'addressDictionary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use @properties

Is any solution for this...

[image]

Comment: Error is self-explanatory, instead of using dictionary with hardcoded keys, use properties of `CLPlacemark`. Also, why are you getting one string, then alloc another string with content of first string, and then put third string with copy of content of second string somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, your correct. Finally I'm used the properties.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Swift 5

```
//let location: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 16.511131, longitude: 80.658725)//Convert lat & lng in to CLLocation

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarksArray, error) in
        print(placemarksArray!)
        if (error) == nil {
            if placemarksArray!.count > 0 {
                let placemark = placemarksArray?[0]
                let address = "\(placemark?.subThoroughfare ?? ""), \(placemark?.thoroughfare ?? ""), \(placemark?.locality ?? ""), \(placemark?.subLocality ?? ""), \(placemark?.administrativeArea ?? ""), \(placemark?.postalCode ?? ""), \(placemark?.country ?? "")"
                print("\(address)")
            }
        }

    }
```

Result Like :

```
**print(placemarksArray!) :** [20/19, Road Number 19, 20/19, Road Number 19, Wadala West, Mumbai, 400031, Maharashtra, India @ <+19.01761470,+72.85616440> +/- 100.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+19.01732600,+72.85634600> radius 70.52', center:<+19.01732600,+72.85634600>, radius:70.52m)]

**print("\(address)") :** 20/19, Road Number 19, Mumbai, Wadala West, Maharashtra, 400031, India
```

In Objective C

```
if (!(error))
    {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];    
        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@",
                             placemark.thoroughfare,
                             placemark.locality,
                             placemark.subLocality, 
                             placemark.administrativeArea, 
                             placemark.postalCode,
                             placemark.country];
        NSLog(@"%@", address);

    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Answer in swift - old way commented out:

```
let street = placemark.thoroughfare! // addressDictionary!["Street"] as? String ?? " "
    let city =  placemark.subAdministrativeArea! // addressDictionary!["City"] as? String ?? " "
    let state = placemark.administrativeArea!//addressDictionary!["State"] as? String ?? " "
    let zip =  placemark.isoCountryCode!// addressDictionary!["ZIP"] as? String ?? " "
    let country = placemark.country! // addressDictionary!["Country"] as? String ?? " "
```