# Swift 5 reverseGeocodeLocation() result in deprecated addressDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, clgeocoder, clplacemark

I'm using a `CLGeoCoder` instance to get the city and country of a given set of coordinates (latitude and longitude) through its method `reverseGeocodeLocation()`.

The documentation specifies that this data should be in `CLPlacemark`'s `country` and `locality` properties but the results only seem to be inside `addressDictionary` property which was deprecated since iOS 11.

[Image of debugging instance showing addressDictionary present but neither country nor locality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zQUg.png)

This therefore works but shows this warning on all three uses of `addressDictionary`:
`'addressDictionary' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use @properties`

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, preferredLocale: nil) { (placemarksArray, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        if let placemark = placemarksArray?.last {
            var city = ""
            if let ct = placemark.addressDictionary?["City"] {
                city = "\(ct), "
            }
            var state = ""
            if let st = placemark.addressDictionary?["State"] {
                state = "\(st), "
            }
            var country = ""
            if let cot = placemark.addressDictionary?["Country"] {
                country = "\(cot)"
            }
            self.cityCountry = "\(city)\(state)\(country)"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried referencing the properties but they just return nil values.

Am I calling the wrong method or is this a bug?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987473/addressdictionary-is-deprecated-first-deprecated-in-ios-11-0-use-properties. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suddenly references to the `country`, `locality` and `subAdministrativeArea` started working! Couldn't figure out what caused them not to work earlier though.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! If you found an answer to your question by yourself, please mark it as accepted. That way it won't show up in the unanswered lists anymore. Cheers!